# RequireJS not honoring relative paths when not loaded at "mysite.com/"

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having some trouble with requirejs and relative paths.

This is in my HTML file:

```
<script data-main="/app/main.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.1/require.js"></script>
```

My config is set up as follows:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/vendor',
    paths: {
        // APP FILES
        'app-base'   : '../app',
        'app-config' : '../config',
        models       : '../models', // where the models and collections are
        templates    : '../templates',
        views        : '../views',
        lib          : '../lib',
        tasks        : '../tasks',
        router       : '../app/router',

        // VENDOR FILES
        marionette : 'backbone.marionette',
    },
    deps: ['router'],
    shim: {...}
});
```

When my app loads from the url "localhost:3000/" or "localhost:3000/applications" all of these paths resolve correctly. But when it's loaded from something like "localhost:3000/applications/app1", the paths resolve incorrectly.

The paths looks like this, respectively.

**Correct:**

"/models/test-model.js"

**Incorrect:**

"/applications/models/test-model.js"

I'm loading my modules using CJS as follows:

```
define( function( require ) {
   var TestModel = require('models/test-model.js');
});
```

When I change the above to this --> `var TestModel = require('/models/test-model.js');`, it works. But this defeats the purpose of using relative paths.

Would love it if someone could help me out. I'm super confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requiring a module, be sure to leave off the .js extension unless you are specifying a complete path.

Comment: Looks like I had to take off the '.js'. Didn't even realize it was there. Thanks!